# How to run .jar in Android and see the results in Android

Tags: java, android

How can I Run a .jar file in Java so that I can see the results? I this I will need to use Android Studio but I have no idea on how to do it. Please help.

Comment: Android doesn't use JRE. So it can't run .jar files but you can include them as libraries.

Answer (score 0):

To use class and method in .jar library file in android you have to use it as a module.To do this follow below steps

1. copy .jar file
2. navigate to android studio "project" folder

   [image: enter code here]
3. paste copied .jar to libs folder

[image]

4. right click on pasted file and click add as library

[image]

Comment: Hello! Will I Also have to program anything else in the app?

Comment: I just want to run the .jar as it is done in an ide and see the results. Thank You

Comment: I actually want to run this jar: https://github.com/blynkkk/blynk-server . I dont have any experience in programming Android or Java. So Please tell me if there is a way possible to run a jar such as this on android. I think this is a netty based server

Comment: To run java file  you have to install jdk and run cmd this   java -jar server-0.41.12.jar -dataFolder /path .please follow the tutorial stated there

Comment: But how can I run the file in android?

Comment: you can not run it in android.you can use it like i answered like above ? please read there docs carefully

Answer (score 0):

Android uses ART not JRE. So it can't run .jar files.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run jar files in Android. But the problem is, it's possible using command execution and Root is needed to do that. A perfect example is this  [Apktool (Android) with Source Code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/apktool/downloads)